# Git: What is the difference between 'git log --graph' and 'git log --graph --all'?

Tags: git, git-log

The command:  `git log --graph`, shows the commit logs with a text-based graphical representation  on the left hand side of the output.

About the option `--all` to limit the output of commits, the [git doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) says:

> **Commit Limiting**
>
> Besides specifying a range of commits that should be listed using the
>   special notations explained in the description, additional commit
>   limiting may be applied.
>
> **--all**
>
> *Pretend as if all the refs in `refs/` are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.*

I don't understand very well the output that I'm getting with this option.

**What are all the refs of** `refs/`**?**

**What is the default value of** `git log --graph` **related to commit limiting ?**

**Concerning commit limits,** **what is the difference between `git log --graph` and `git log --graph --all` ?**

Comment: sounds to me like relating to the current a special or all branches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--all` will include commits from all branches, including `refs/tags` and `refs/remotes`.

If you instead want all branches only, you can use `--branches`.

`git log --graph --all`

```
* 456 (master)
|
* 123           * 789 (feature-1)
|  _____________|
| /
|/
```

`git log --graph`

```
* 456 (master)
|
* 123
```

Concerning commit limits, there's not difference between the two commands: if you don't specify a limit, all commits will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The `--all` option let you see all local branches (I added `--oneline` for a shorter example):

For example, with a commit on `master` and two feature branches (each with one commit):

```
$ git log --graph --oneline      
* 389c7c6 1st commit             // <- branch master

$ git log --graph --all --oneline 
* 03a21a0 feature2 stuff         // <- branch feature2
| * 2c848b3 feature1 stuff       // <- branch feature1
|/  
* 389c7c6 1st commit             // <- branch master
```

This is the same as `git log --graph master feature1 feature2`: the `--all` options adds all the local branches and tags (the refs in `.git/refs/`) for you.

Regarding Commit Limiting: without limit, you will get the whole history (accessible from the current branch).